# How do I reset the binding of Ctrl+Tab?

Tags: 14.04, gnome, shortcut-keys, ubuntu-gnome

I was using gnome-tweak-tool and momentarily bound Ctrl+Tab to one of the window-switching navigations. After clearing the rebinding, it didn't go back to doing what it used to do: switching tabs within a window like Firefox's.

I'd like to get this behavior back. Does anyone know how? I'm in Ubuntu-Gnome 14.04 LTS; not sure what other information would be helpful.

Comment: It would be best to provide a screen shot of your gnome-tweak-tool settings.  Also, you should be able to re-set your Firefox shortcut behaviour with this link [https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/customizable-shortcuts/] to a mozilla addon to customize keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Thanks. Everything in the "Typing" section of gnome-tweak-settings is "Disabled" except for Swap ESC and Caps Lock. In the Keyboard -> Shortcuts settings, Ctrl + Tab isn't bound anywhere.

Comment: Then check in  `settings>keyboard>shortcuts` and look carefully at every section for your key combination.  If you find any shortcut mapped to Ctrl+Tab, change it.  My shortcuts do not contain any Ctrl+Tab setting and in Firefox it does switch tabs as expected.